# how to make shortcut keys in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to run specific code through shortcuts defined for my specific program. For example if I click <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then I want my program to show customers list. I have tried form's keydown event with following code

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then
    Form6.button4.performclick()
End If
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me in this?

I'm using vb.net in visual studio 2005 to develop my application

Comment: `F1` is reserved in Windows for help. `Ctrl+C` is usually used for `Clipboard Copy`. These particular key choices are probably a bad idea.

Comment: I've also tried other keys like 'O' or 'F4' but this also doesn't work...Form6 is the form to view customers and button4 click event contains the code to print the customers list

Comment: Please consider marking an answer as correct, or add your own solution and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Private Sub frmCustomerDetails_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' When the form loads, the KeyPreview property is set to True.
    ' This lets the form capture keyboard events before
    ' any other element in the form.
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub

    Private Sub frmCustomerDetails_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If (e.Alt AndAlso (e.KeyCode = Keys.P)) Then
        ' When Alt + P is pressed, the Click event for the print
        ' button is raised.
        RaiseEvent btnPrintCustomerDetails.Click
    End If
End Sub
```

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/839201)

Although, you'd be better to create your own event and raise that instead of raising the button's click event.

Answer (score 3):

"An access key is an underlined character in the text of a menu, menu item, or the label of a control such as a button. With an access key, the user can "click" a button by pressing the ALT key in combination with the predefined access key. For example, if a button runs a procedure to print a form, and therefore its Text property is set to "Print," adding an ampersand before the letter "P" causes the letter "P" to be underlined in the button text at run time. The user can run the command associated with the button by pressing ALT+P. You cannot have an access key for a control that cannot receive focus."

[Access Keys](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbd5w3b8%28v=vs.85%29.aspx&ei=Or45T6vDCYXhtgeMr5z1Cg&usg=AFQjCNFVoyUOFouX2zP2w6IpD8vCywDcbQ&sig2=AoWGhxOgxcVB2zgp16kypQ)

Try access keys?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple way to do something like that:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyPress

    If Keys.T + Keys.ControlKey Then
        TextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.SelectedText    
    End If

End Sub
```

This is from 2010 though.

Answer (score 1):

[How to Capture Shortcut Keys in Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839201) There are some VB examples there.

Comment: The content should be put in your answer, as links tend to die.

Comment: Sorry, page not found.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to implement shortcuts by adding a menu for your shortcuts, add menu items for each shortcut, and then bind the shortcut to the menu items. This is nice because it documents the available shortcuts and makes the coding very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but you should set `keyPreview = true` in your Form

Answer (score 0):

I saw the answers listed and this is quite old but try this. The hotkeys are set as alt+d or alt+c as indicated. This difference in code between what they are giving you and what i am giving you is that this works even when the application is minimized.

```
Public Const MOD_ALT As Integer = &H1           'Alt key
Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312       '


<DllImport("User32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function RegisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifiers As Integer,  ByVal vk As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("User32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function UnregisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
        Dim id As IntPtr = m.WParam
        Select Case (id.ToString)
            Case "100"
                MessageBox.Show("You pressed ALT+D key combination")
            Case "200"
                MessageBox.Show("You pressed ALT+C key combination")
        End Select
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs)  Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100)
    UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 200)
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100, MOD_ALT, Keys.D)
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 200, MOD_ALT, Keys.C)
end sub
```

Comment: "Amen Ayach" Your correct. That would be needed, sorry for the oversight.

Comment: "SpectralGhost" & 'Barry Franklin' that works but are they available when the application is minimized? I don't believe so. Implementation of either depends on your application or what your client wants.

Answer (score 0):

I have encounterd with same situation, I used menustrip and asigned shortkeys and used performclick function and set the property of menustrip to visible false and it worked fine.